# React Native - "ProgressBarAndroid is deprecated. Use ActivityIndicator instead"

Tags: android, mobile, react-native

I'm running into the error: "ProgressBarAndroid is deprecated. Use ActivityIndicator instead" but when I go to the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.42/docs/progressbarandroid.html#progressbarandroid), it doesn't look like it's actually deprecated.

I'm using

`react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.40.0`

[image]

Here's my current related code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ProgressViewIOS, ProgressBarAndroid, Platform } from 'react-native';

export default function ProgressBar(props) {

  if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){
    return (
        <ProgressViewIOS
          progress={props.progress}
          style={{height: 3}}
          progressViewStyle={'bar'}
          progressTintColor={props.progressTintColor}
        />
      )
  }else if(Platform.OS === 'android'){
    return <ProgressBarAndroid styleAttr="Horizontal" progress={props.progress} />
  }else{
    console.log('NO PROGRESS')
    return null

  }

}
```

Even though I specify `styleAttr="Horizontal"` (which I believe should set indeterminate as false) my progress bar in android is indeterminate (it just keeps moving). This is not the same functionality I see on iOS. iOS works as expected.

Another error says "You are manually calling a React.PropType validation function for `indeterminate` prop on `ProgressBarAndroid`, however as you see in my code that is not the case. I also don't believe there is a third party doing this as the project is small and I haven't seen this error until I implemented as shown above:

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If it's warning you that it's deprecated why not just use the API its suggesting? What use case do you have that you feel it's necessary to use `ProgressViewIOS` over the component that it's being replaced by? (Especially since `ActivityIndciator` works on both iOS and Android)

To answer your question it may not be deprecated in the docs, but it is warning you that it has been deprecated in favor of the new API. You can continue to use it if you wish, but you won't get any updates and it may be removed in future versions.

Comment: ActivityIndciator isn't the same as ProgressBarAndroid, which wraps the Android-only ProgressBar. I need a progress bar not a loading spinner.